# UK plug socket won't turn off

Tags: electrical, socket

I have recently replaced a double socket that had a short circuit fault on the right hand socket with a new one from B&Q. After long periods of use the right hand switch refuses to stay off. If I turn it off it will just spring back on by itself. After a couple of days I replaced the socket with one of the same model and the new one is doing the same thing on the same side.

I'm no qualified electrician but I am competent and it was a straight swap of wires so pretty sure it hasn't gone wrong.

Any ideas as to what it could be? At first I thought a faulty socket hence the replacement but seems odd that the second unit is doing the same thing.
Thanks in advance

Edit: Here is a link to a video clip that shows the problem. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2coson85m3z7e2/Video%2011-04-2016%2019%2014%2051.mov?dl=0

Comment: Could be a faulty design or batch.

Comment: Is this a socket with a built-in knob switch? If so, then perhaps the  knob's axis is being pushed off-center by the fixture? (A picture would really help.)

Comment: In the UK every receptacle outlet has a small switch right next to it, i.e. a duplex receptacle has 2 switches.  If that seems overkill, don't ask where they put fuses!

Comment: When you physically mount the socket, is the mounting surface smooth and flat?  Are you putting a lot of force on the screws when you mount it?  I wonder if something about your mounting is bending or damaging the socket in a way which is causing this.  Or your particular usage is pulling the limits of current, and it's cheaply made.  Obviously a third of the same model will do the same thing, I'd go up to the next better one.  In the US I'd say use the $4 outlets instead of the 60 cent outlets.

Comment: Thanks for the advice so far. Tempted to say faulty design but its a fairly standard piece of kit I would have thought?
@Harper - There doesn't seem to be any massive amount of force when screwing into the back box so I don't think its bending the face plate at all. If it is then its very weak.

Comment: I'm from the US so... If it's an RCD (a UK style GFCI, right?) it will not reset if there is a fault condition, assuming they behave like GFCI's. I don't think you've cleared the fault that blew out the first one.

Comment: Have you thought that what your plugging into the socket could be causing the problem ?

Comment: @IanMalone Thanks Ian, it did occur to me at the time but it was doing it even without a plug in the socket. It was a faulty socket rather than what was going into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two sockets were bought from the same branch of B&Q i'd bet on a faulty batch, possiblly combined with a marginal design. My advice would be to return the socket as faulty and replace with one of a different brand.

Comment: I think that might be the answer. I will take it back when I get chance and get a different model. If that is the case then I shall mark this answer as correct. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't actually find the receipt now which is annoying but that shouldn't stop an accepted answer on here. Thank you